# How can Activity Viewmodel get data from a Fragment child ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm developing a Xamarin.Android application using MvvmCross and I'm trying to get stored data into Fragment Viewmodel from the main activity Viewmodel.

This is what I have.

[image]

And I'm using

- ActivityViewModel for the activity
- FragmentAViewModel for FragmentA
- FragmentBViewModel for FragmentB

So, I'm trying to access to a FragmentAViewModel.SomeProperty from ActivityViewModel object.

Is it possible?

I'm using IMvxMessenger as a workaround to "send" a notification to ActivityViewModel with the content of the property I want to acceess.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative is to use the dependency injection system to create a singleton which can be used as a shared context between view models.

**Example**

```
public interface ISharedContext 
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SharedContext : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged, ISharedContext 
{
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }
}
```

Register the `SharedContext` in your App class

```
Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ISharedContext, SharedContext>();
```

Usage in view models. You can then bind directly to the `SharedContext` or assign to its properties and use in different view models.

```
public class FragmentAViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public ISharedShoppingCart SharedContext { get; }

    public FragmentAViewModel(ISharedContext sharedContext)
    {
        SharedContext = sharedContext;
    }
}

public class ActivityViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public ISharedShoppingCart SharedContext { get; }

    public ActivityViewModel(ISharedContext sharedContext)
    {
        SharedContext = sharedContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I was thinking in something more complex that I never thought in a simple and very functional option like yours. Thank you very much.